# how to see Types of Log being captured in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, logging

What are the types of logs being captured in SP 2013? Where can we find that what are the logs that are currently enabled in SP 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different kind of Logs available in SharePoint 2013.

- Diagnostics Logs:
  These logs are captured in Window Event Viewer
- Audit Logs:
  These logs are associate with Content DB and it is at site collection level So we are able to see this logs from Site Settings.
- Usage Logs:
  These logs are captured in 15 hive folder in SharePoint On Premise server.

Answer (score 0):

Sam correctly mentioned the types of logs. So, just adding to his answer.

By default, SharePoint logs are stored in the 15 hive folder. The location of that would be :

```
%commonprogramfiles%/Microsoft Shared/web server extensions/15/Logs
```

Full path would be something like:

```
c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\LOGS
```

There you will find lots of files with `.log` extension with the date format. These files have the logging details of mostly all errors, warnings, messages that occur in SharePoint and its related services. So sometimes when you have an error, you get a correlation id.

Using that ID, you should open the latest log with and search for that error. The log files can be opened in notepad or any text editor.

I would also suggest that you install the ULS viewer tool as it provides a simplified view of the log files.

Download link - [ULS viewer tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44020)

Answer (score 0):

To know specifically what SP logs are captured run the cmdlet from the Sharepoint PowerShell console:

Get-SPLogLevel

This will give you list of logging settings for Sharepoint.

As previous answers say there are other logs (IIS, DB) that will be relevant for troubleshooting of SP issues.